# Can I change expiration date of a gpg key I've already sent to a key server?

Tags: gnupg, asymmetric, key-server, expiration-date

[ArchLinux wiki page on GnuPG](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Use_a_keyserver) reads

> Once a key has been submitted to a keyserver, it cannot be deleted from the server.

Does that mean that also the expiration date with which I published the key via `gpg --send-keys key-id` cannot be changed?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the expiration date locally:

```
gpg --edit-key <your-key-id>
expire
#Now specify how long the key should be valid
save
```

Update the modified key on keyserver:

```
gpg --send-keys <your-key-id>
```

A key cannot be deleted, but it can be changed.

Comment: FWIW -- Every year (on my birthday) I set my key to expire in 55 weeks and re-upload it to key exchanges and my GitHub public Gist.  When I was taught this, the idea was that you were telling everyone to not trust a key past a certain date, but with the option of expanding (which I do each year).  That way if you lose access to the key, it'll self expire in a years time.  (think "dead man's switch" for your key.)  Otherwise you keep re-upping each year and keep using the same key.

Comment: @Ruscal "Good morning honey! Do you know what day it is?" - "The day to update my public key expiration date, woo!"